# Динамическая смена контента на странице. Как и чем правильно реализовать?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, html5

**Ситуация** - есть 10 кнопок на HTML странице, под ними расположился div в котором должны отображаться картинки.

**Проблема** - нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "1" отображалась картинка "1", при нажатии на "2" отображалась вторая картинка и т.д. без перезагрузки всей страницы.

**Вопрос** - Как и чем это грамотно и правильно реализовать?

P.S. Буду крайне признателен за ссылки на полезные статьи. Спасибо.

Comment: Javascript вам в помощь, именно для этого он и был придумал. Для более быстрого написания на нём, рекомендую jQuery, если любите помучиться вначале, то AngulaJS.

Comment: @Vartlok, с ангуляром вроде в начале как раз все хорошо :-) а вот потоооом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это решается с помощью JavaScript. Можно сделать и на "голом" языке, но я так его и не изучил, работаю с фреймворком jQuery, на нем и приведу пример. Самый простой пример, ссылки на картинки записываете в атрибут кнопки (например `data-img`), делаете обработчик события при нажатии кнопки (В jQuery есть разные способы навесить обработчик, в примере я привязываю обработчик к элементам на странице которые имеют класс - `my_btn`, и описываю что делать при событии `click`), в обработчике формируется тег img с ссылкой из атрибута кнопки и вставляется в div затирая все что в нем есть.

```
<a href="#" class="my_btn" data-img="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg">1</a>
<a href="#" class="my_btn" data-img="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">2</a>
<a href="#" class="my_btn" data-img="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-534897989.jpg">3</a>
<a href="#" class="my_btn" data-img="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg">4</a>
<div id="images"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".my_btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $img = $('<img/>').attr("src",$(this).data("img"));
        $("#images").html($img);
    });
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jrkq8fpn/

Comment: preventDefault работает в хроме, но в мозилле, например, нужно обходить этот момент по-другому: в событие click нужно возвращать false. Вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367195/preventdefault-wont-work-on-firefox) сказано подробнее. Буквально вчера тут, кстати, поднимался этот момент в каком-то вопросе

Comment: @Mr.Brightside Откровенно говоря не сталкивался с подобной проблемой, знаю о возвращении false, по той же сылке человек говорит что это эквивалент `preventDefault()` и `stopPropagation()`, при этом `stopPropagation()` прекратит выполнение всех обработчиков для родителей, что может быть проблемой. Данный код просто для примера, что бы человеку было немного проще, могут быть разные ситуации и проблемы, не настаиваю на единственно верном варианте.

Answer (score 1):

В помощь вам JQuery - фраймфорк js.Так как js позволяет без перегрузки страницы что-то на ней изменять , то это плагин окажется вам полезным. Возможно вам поможет анимация , в JQuery легко на теги накладывать события и дальше что-то на странице делать ,можете анимацией показывать свои картинки.
Вот ссылка на анимацию http://jqbook.net.ru/jquery/Effects
вот то как события делаются http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F